# Define local variable in function?

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this

```
initialize : {  
    method : function() {
        this.__. //--> do another thing
        ... //--> so many
        this.__.params. //--> do another thing
        ... //--> so many
    }           
}
```

and the method of this object call by another function.  As you can see, we have many lines that refer to `this.__` and `this.__.` params, and for preventing this, I declare local variables `T` and `P` like below

```
initialize : {  
    method : function() {
        var T = this.__, P = T.params;
        T. //--> do another thing
        ... //--> so many
        P. //--> do another thing
        ... //--> so many
    }           
}
```

as I mentioned before the method calls by another function called `caller`.

Is it possible to not declare locale variables in the method function and instead define them in scope of the `caller` function and pass it to the method ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have another object which is calling `method` as if it were its own method (and therefore `this` references the other object). I'm assuming that since you're trying to simplify this bit of code, it's a user-extendable part of some library. I don't really see any problem with it as-is (except for the `__` name, which is a bit odd). I guess I'd need more context to know why you want to simplify it. You certainly shouldn't have the caller define the variables for you (which is impossible anyway), but I don't see why you can't just use normal parameters?

Comment: If you can tell us what `this` and `this.__` is, maybe we can provide *another* approach.

Comment: Thanks, in fact I just write a framework base on aspect oriented programming for the developers and it's include a lot of components and I try to simplify it, for example I told the developers that follow as example number two because it reduces the code size that must be send from server to client (because of the problem of bandwidth), and after a while I thought if is it possible to declare locale variable in another scope and pass it to another scope. anyway Thanks for you help.

Comment: If you set up your server to gzip resources (which you should), this isn't an issue anyway. Also you should be minifying your scripts before publishing them (e.g. using the closure compiler). I would still suggest that parameters are the way to go (if not what you already have), and you shouldn't put a lot of effort into saving 10 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Not much to review ;)

- As @Dave mentioned, `__` is a bit of an odd named, for sure it does not give away what it does
- You might consider storing `__.params` separately in `this.parameters` or `this.options`

I would need more code to give deeper, insightful comments ;)

Comment: Hypothetical code is usually unreviewable, which is why we consider such questions off-topic.